# "Como si fuera representar" o "como si fuera para representar"?

Tags: preposiciones, subjuntivo, pretérito-imperfecto

I'm trying to say "the story starts suddenly as if to represent an intentional eclipse..."

Would it be:

> "El cuento empieza de repente como si fuera **para** representar" 
>   or
>   "El cuento empieza de repente como si fuera representar"

I thought it was the last one, but Google translate told me it was the first option.

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct answer would be

> ... empieza de repente como si fuera **para** representar

You can't actually say "como si fuera representar", the way to say it is:

> ... empieza de repente como si fuera **a** representar un eclipse.

This second one would mean something closer to the first one (like if it was to represent and eclipse). I think you could go with both prepositions, `para` and `a` and there would be no practical difference.

You could also use:

> ... empieza de repente como si **representara**

The subjuntivo is a verb tense that can show *purpose*, *wish*, *uncertainty* or *doubt*, among other things, so I think works well for this transaltion.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that they are two different verbs, ser and ir. The forms in indicative would be "es para representar" and "va a representar".

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to say it would be

> El cuento empieza de repente como representando ...

I realize that it will not translate through an online translator correctly, but online translators aren't the least bit reliable.  At the least, they can provide you with a start  research more, like with DRAE.